# Употребление прилагательных с существительным

Tags: согласование

Как правильно сказать: *местный и областной* **бюджет** или ...**бюджеты**? Допустимы ли оба варианта?

Comment: допустимы ли оба варианта?

Answer (score 2):

Если бюджет один ,то правильно: бюджет,если несколько,то бюджеты.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы здесь писал в единственном. 
Местный бюджет и областной бюджет - это термины. Если множественном, то получится "местные и областные бюджеты".

Comment: А разве не *местный и областной бюджеты* получится?

Comment: ну это - у кого как )))
Я о том, что не стоит ставить во множественное одну часть термина, оставляя вторую в единственном. Это в общем-то личное мнение, но подобное неоднократно обсуждалосью 
Одно дело сказать "большое и красное яблоко", когда определения можно отнести к одному определяемому, совсем другое "областной и местный бюджет", когда ясно что это бюджеты разные  и их невозможно воспринять как единое целое. Хотя, коенсно, контекст бы не помешал и тут. Может автор как раз и хочет подчеркнуть то, что это бюджеты ***разные***. Тогда, может, "бюджеты" действительно уместнее.